# vfork() system call

Tags: c, fork, systems-programming

I read that the new process created using vfork() system call executes as a thread in the parent's address space and until the child thread doesnot calls exit() or exec() system call, the parent is blocked. So I wrote a program using vfork() system call

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <unistd.h>

int main()  
 {  
      pid_t pid;  
      printf("Parent\n");  
      pid = vfork();  
      if(pid==0)  
      {  
          printf("Child\n");  
      }  
      return 0;  
  }
```

I got the output as follows:

```
 Parent  
 Child  
 Parent  
 Child  
 Parent  
 Child  
 ....  
 ....  
 ....
```

I was assuming that the return statement must be calling the exit() system call internally so I was expecting the output as only

```
Parent  
Child
```

Can  somebody explain me why actually it is not stopping and continuously printing for infinite loop.

Comment: By the way, `vfork()` is basically obsolete. It's been ripped from the latest POSIX standard, and with modern copy-on-write semantics, gains you little if any performance or memory savings. Just use `fork()`. It's plenty fast, works on everything that claims to be *nix-ish, and doesn't put any restrictions on what you can do.

Comment: The only time `vfork` is still needed is on wannabe-POSIX MMU-less microcontroller-based junk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the man page for [`vfork`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/vfork.2.html) very carefully:

> The vfork() function has the same effect as fork(2), except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store the return value from vfork(), or returns from the function in which vfork() was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling _exit(2) or one of the exec(3) family of functions.

(above is from the POSIX part of the man page, so applies (potentially) to other environments than Linux).

You're calling `printf` and returning from the child, so the behavior of your program is undefined.

Comment: Yep, Mat's dead-on. It says `_exit()` or exec*() and it _means it_. `return` is _not_ just a simple `_exit()` call, and `_exit()` is different from `exit()`.

Comment: Indeed, returning from `main` potentially destroys the parent's stack. It's **very dangerous**. I would go so far as saying you should never use `vfork` at all. It was omitted from POSIX for good reasons.

Comment: What's the point of `vfork` if I cant call any function or modify a variable?

Comment: @TheLogicGuy: you can call `exec` and friends, that's pretty much the only use case AFAIK. Super weird function though, best not to use it at all.